# MySQL: Get the begin and end time of consecutive times

Tags: mysql, timespan

I have a table with consecutive times and dates for an agenda.

```
ID  date        begin_time  end_time
1   05-02-15    19:00:00    19:05:00
2   05-02-15    19:05:00    19:10:00
3   05-02-15    19:10:00    19:15:00
4   05-02-15    19:15:00    19:20:00
5   05-02-15    19:20:00    19:25:00
6   05-02-15    19:25:00    19:30:00
7   05-02-15    19:30:00    19:35:00
8   05-02-15    19:35:00    19:40:00
9   06-02-15    19:00:00    19:05:00
10  06-02-15    19:05:00    19:10:00
11  06-02-15    19:10:00    19:15:00
12          
13          
14  06-02-15    19:25:00    19:30:00
15  06-02-15    19:30:00    19:35:00
16  06-02-15    19:35:00    19:40:00
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54d9f6

As you can see on 05-02-15 the time from 19:00 until 19:40 is consecutive

As you can see on 06-02-15 the time from 19:00 until 19:15 is consecutive

As you can see on 06-02-15 the time from 19:25 until 19:40 is consecutive

The begin time and end time always have a 5 minute difference.

I want to have all the different dates with the begin_time and end_time. So the result for above table would be:

```
date        begin_time  end_time
05-02-15    19:00:00    19:40:00
06-02-15    19:00:00    19:15:00
06-02-15    19:25:00    19:40:00
```

**Idea for an approach**

The first step to get all consecutive parts is done by this query, but the difference is that in this query all distinct dates are selected:

```
set @x=15;
select distinct t1.date
from
    `agenda_specialists` as t1 join
    `agenda_specialists` as t2 on
        t2.date=t1.date and
        t2.begin>=t1.begin and
        t2.begin<addtime(t1.begin,sec_to_time(@x*60))
group by t1.id
having count(*)=@x/5
```

Which is taken from this question [MySQL: a timespan available within consecutive times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28093982/987864) where almost similar data needs to be retrieved. Although we don't need a specific @x value in this case.